# Werkzeug debugger: Most recent call first & focus console

Tags: python, django, werkzeug

With the Werkzeug debugger. How can I make the recent call first instead of last? And how can I make it so Werkzeug debugger automatically focuses the console at the most recent call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not configurable, and probably never will be. There has been some discussion about [changing the order of calls in the debugger](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues/116).